# These are my session settings in htaccess file. Are they secure enough?

Tags: security, session

I know the lifetime is a little bit too long, but i just want to simulate the "remember me" function. Except that, are my settings secure enough ?

```
php_value session.cookie_httponly 1
php_value session.cookie_secure 1
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "60"
php_value session.cookie_lifetime "2592000"
php_flag session.use_only_cookies 1
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
php_value session.entropy_length 512
php_value session.name "mysessionname"
php_value session.hash_function sha512
php_value session.hash_bits_per_character 6
php_value session.entropy_file  /dev/urandom
```

Comment: secure for WHAT? security isn't just a magical checkbox that makes everything totally secure or totally insecure.

Comment: i mean, if the standard recommendations are given ?

Comment: Check out the [guidelines for asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make your requirements more concrete. Without additional context about your goals and requirements, this is like asking "am I fit enough?" ...I might be fit enough for a walk around the block, but not for competing in the Olympics!

Comment: i want to prevent session hijacking